# Remove "earned" badges from the badge tracking function

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badge-progress

In the new profile badge tracking function, the pop-up window to choose which badge to track includes data on badges we've *already earned*.

However, I see no use for showing *earned* badges within this function, as the entire purpose of this functionality is specifically to track badges we have *not earned*.

Showing earned badges just clutters the area with unwanted things, badges we've already earned are not really *relevant* here.

There are already *two other* places we can see all the badges we've have *earned*:
[The badge list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230506/james?tab=badges) on our main profile page;
The [site's main badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges), as *earned* ones are ticked;

Do we need a *3rd* place to see *earned* badges?

### Proposal

All tabs within the "Select your next badge" pop-up area to only show *unearned* badges.

The "Available" tab currently shows only *unearned* badges, and so my proposal would make this tab obsolete:
Remove the "Available" tab completely.

With *earned* badges removed entirely from this function, the "All" tab would then provide the same functionality as the "Available" tag currently does, as the "All" tab would show:
"Unearned" badges for "Gold", "Silver", and "Bronze" badges.

And the option would remain to use "Gold", "Silver", and "Bronze" tabs to choose "unearned" badges separately as required.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a great idea to show only *unearned badges* but those badges we can see in **Available** tab.

I just want to modify your recommendation that they should be sorted by earned and unearned badges.
Means earned badge should be visible but at the end of the unearned badge.

Support I am clicking on **Bronze** tab then there should listed all badges but first unearned and after that earned.

Hope you will also be agree with it as it is not hard work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re: "earned and unearned" - do you not think a function for "track which badge you want to earn" is pointless showing badges you've already earned? I still want to use the Gold, Silver, Bronze to sort which one I want to go for. Why show "You have earned X badge" when I'm trying to select one I *have not earned*. In essence, the "Available" tab is obsolete as every badge in this area should only be "available to *earn*". It's like going into a supermarket and shelves have empty wrappers on them...

Comment: @James There is already have this functionality badges which are just near to earn with your effort are shown in _All_ tab

Comment: I think you are missing the *prime* point of my proposal. I simply do not want "*earned*" badges in a function which allows me to track "*unearned*" badges. They're just noise and in my way. Click "Track next badge" and see all ones you've earned. Why are they there? It's a tracker for things I can earn, not things I cannot earn :)

Comment: @James I know you want to show the only unearned badge in the view and want to show only earned badge. But you know many badge are not there listed in the progress popup. In the previous comment, by mistake I have write All, it is Available tab.